# How encrypt a string with XOR without include strange characters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encryption, cryptography, xor

The following code works fine, but i want that not include strange characters on encrypted string, like '\x03' for example. How to achieve this?

```
string XOR_Encryption(string toBeEncrypted, string sKey)
{
    string sEncrypted(toBeEncrypted);
    unsigned int iKey(sKey.length()), iIn(toBeEncrypted.length()), x(0);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iIn; i++)
    {
        sEncrypted[i] = toBeEncrypted[i] ^ sKey[x];
        if (++x == iKey) { x = 0; }
    }
    return sEncrypted;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
    string message = "gbpi";
    string Key("Q4s4R4t");

    string encrypted_message = XOR_Encryption(message, Key);
    cout << "encoded: " << encrypted_message << endl;

    string decryptedMessage = XOR_Encryption(encrypted_message, Key);
    cout << "decoded: " << decryptedMessage << endl;
```

Comment: Encode the output hex, or base64. Note that you have to decode before decrypting.

Comment: @kelalaka, thank you. Worked.

Comment: Please write an answer that should contain full code and with some explanations. I'll upvote...

Comment: As an alternative you might try using [Vigenere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher) encryption, which always produces alphabetic characters (or alphanumeric with a simple extension).  The advantage being that the cyphertext is the same length as the plaintext, unlike Hex or Base64.

Comment: @kelalaka, *"`Please write an answer that should contain full code and with some explanations. I'll upvote...`"* - done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686526/how-encrypt-a-string-with-xor-without-include-strange-characters?noredirect=1#comment107370240_60686526) of **@kelalaka**, here is a solution using Hex encode:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

string XOR_Encryption(string toBeEncrypted, string sKey)
{
    string sEncrypted(toBeEncrypted);
    unsigned int iKey(sKey.length()), iIn(toBeEncrypted.length()), x(0);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < iIn; i++)
    {
        sEncrypted[i] = toBeEncrypted[i] ^ sKey[x];
        if (++x == iKey) { x = 0; }
    }
    return sEncrypted;
}

void stream2hex(const string str, string& hexstr, bool capital = false)
{
    hexstr.resize(str.size() * 2);
    const size_t a = capital ? 'A' - 1 : 'a' - 1;

    for (size_t i = 0, c = str[0] & 0xFF; i < hexstr.size(); c = str[i / 2] & 0xFF)
    {
        hexstr[i++] = c > 0x9F ? (c / 16 - 9) | a : c / 16 | '0';
        hexstr[i++] = (c & 0xF) > 9 ? (c % 16 - 9) | a : c % 16 | '0';
    }
}

void hex2stream(const string hexstr, string& str)
{
    str.resize((hexstr.size() + 1) / 2);

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < str.size(); i++, j++)
    {
        str[i] = (hexstr[j] & '@' ? hexstr[j] + 9 : hexstr[j]) << 4, j++;
        str[i] |= (hexstr[j] & '@' ? hexstr[j] + 9 : hexstr[j]) & 0xF;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string text = "text";
    string Key("password");

    string encrypted_message = XOR_Encryption(text, Key);
    stream2hex(encrypted_message, encrypted_message, true);
    cout << "encoded: " << encrypted_message << endl;

    hex2stream(encrypted_message, encrypted_message);
    string decryptedMessage = XOR_Encryption(encrypted_message, Key);
    cout << "decoded: " << decryptedMessage << endl;

   getch();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did. Remember to write some explanations at least for functions?